# Cache-Control no cache

Tags: .htaccess, caching, cloudflare

I have the following from http://web-sniffer.net/ :

```
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

I use Cloudflare and Custom Expired Rules for caching, but in the browser it seems that they are not caching.

Why is this happening?

Rules:

```
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` contents?

Comment: yes, sorry. I forgot them

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we knew the specific domain name here, also I would recommend opening a support ticket directly with CloudFlare. Our support team can then check your specific account settings, but for obvious privacy reasons can't discuss those here.

Disclaimer: I work at CloudFlare.